# Can JavaScript fetch event capture 303 redirect on Safari?

Tags: javascript, safari, fetch-api

I am trying to work around an issue that appears to only affect Safari browsers for a Moodle site I support.
When an file is embedded in an "embed" or "object" tag and the src url returns a 303 redirect Safari errors and does not load the redirect url.

Can I write JavaScript (that will work in Safari) to listen to the fetch event for the src url read the 303 response and then recreate the "embed" or "object" tag with the url returned by the 303 response?

Edit: The error does only appear to happen for some file types. PDF and Word files seem to produce the error. Testing with a PDF file I have had the dev tools stop responding or occasionally the browser window stop responding when testing on an Apple computer. The error also still occurs in Chrome on iOS, so seems to be specific to browser engine. I am guessing it is just a different interpretation/implementation of the standard around how the object tag / embed tag.

Comment: I can't repro: https://jsfiddle.net/98m0qhy4/ on Safari 17.0 (19616.1.27.211.1). What kind of "file" are you embedding? Does an `error` event fire on the DOM elements? Is the resource considered same-origin?

Comment: (For the above fiddle to work you may have to visit https://picayune-nebulous-point.glitch.me/redirect manually before to "wake-up" the redirection server)